# Remove "align" attribute on images

Tags: images, customization

I'm trying to get rid of the non W3C compliant "align" attribute generated with any images.

For that, I'm using the simple_html_dom library. Here's the code i'm using :

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'clean_image_attributes', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'clean_image_attributes', 10 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'clean_image_attributes', 10 );

function clean_image_attributes($html)
{
    $output = new simple_html_dom();
    $output->load($html);

    foreach ($output->find("img") as $img)
    {
        if (isset($img->align))
        {
            $img->align = null;
            $img->class .= ' clearfix';
        }
    }

    $html = $output->save();
    return $html;
}
```

What the function does is just looking if the image has the align attribute and remove it. This works pretty well, except that when I call the_content(), the layout of my post is kinda broken, the

got removed but I have no idea why...

Comment: Part of your question got cut off by formatting. What part got removed? (I see "the [something's missing here] got removed...").

Comment: Can you tell me your site link so that i can debug it?

Comment: Sorry, all my paragraphs tags got removed. Here's a link : www.deenastic.com.

As you can see for example on the first post, all the text goes on 1 line, but there should be 3 2 paragraphs instead